# WPF TabControl header issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, header, tabcontrol

I am making an app in WPF that displays an image which can be dragged and zoomed. Bottom, right and upper sides contain some UI elements like buttons and in the center I have a TabControl to which I add TabItems in the code of ViewModel. These TabItems consists of their content (an image) and a header where I have tab buttons. The problem I have is that an image I drag covers the header but not the buttons as you can see on the screenshot. **The behavior I expect is to have this image hidden underneath the entire header, not only buttons.** It only happens with the bottom side. When I drag the image to the top or right it gets hidden behind the sides like it's supposed to.

[Header issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7dTF.png)

I tried to change its background, opacity and ZIndex but nothing worked for me.

Here is my code.

XAML:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" TabStripPlacement="Bottom" Background="LightGray" ItemsSource="{Binding LayoutTabs}" 
                    SelectedIndex="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

C#:

```
            LayoutTabs = new BindableCollection<TabItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < _content.LayoutImages.Count; i++)
            {
                DrawingImage drawing = _content.LayoutImages.ElementAt(i);

                Image image = new Image() { Source = drawing };
                image.MouseMove += OnMouseMove;

                var container = new LayoutContainer()
                {
                    Background = Brushes.WhiteSmoke,
                    Child = image,
                    Focusable = true,
                };

                var tabItem = new TabItem()
                {
                    Header = _content.GetLayoutName(i),
                    Content = container
                };

                LayoutTabs.Add(tabItem);
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried editing the control template or did you try the background and zindex only on the tabcontrol/tabitem ?

Comment: I tried to play with the styles but apparently I was doing it wrong. Editing a template copy   like you suggested in your answer worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behaviour is due to the headerpanels background being set to transparent in the default control template. If you right click the tabcontrol in the Designer window (not xaml editor) and click on Edit Template->Edit a Copy you get a copy of that tempalte and can then modify the headerpanel with your BackgroundColor and if need be increase the Zindex:

```
[....]
//this is the line to make your changes on:
 <TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/> 
[....]
```